# React Native Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid

Tags: ios, react-native, mkmapview, android-mapview

I'm building an iOS app with React Native and I'm trying to display a map. However, I'm running into a problem. Whenever I'm trying to display the `MapView` element I get the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) 
but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from 
the file it's defined in.

Check the render method of `Main`.

This error is located at:
    in Main (at App.js:69)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)

createFiberFromElementType
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:974:90
createFiberFromElement
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:954:20
reconcileSingleElement
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:1403:26
reconcileChildFibers
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:1457:40
reconcileChildrenAtPriority
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:1634:54
reconcileChildren
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:1631:12
finishClassComponent
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:1669:12
updateClassComponent
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:1659:12
beginWork
    ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:1786:23
```

This is my `Main` component, which is exactly the same as demonstrated in the [MapView documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/mapview.html) on the React Native website (except that I set `showsUserLocation` to `false`, which not causing the error):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MapView } from 'react-native';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        style={{height: 200, margin: 40}}
        showsUserLocation={false}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

The error refers to line 69 in `App.js` which is the `return` statement in the `render` method. For completeness, this is the `App` class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import MainIOS from "./ios/Main";

class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (<MainIOS />);
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

How can I resolve this issue? I prefer not to use any 3rd party packages or libraries, rather just standard React Native components.

Comment: What is your version of react-native?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it states in [react-native docs for MapView (v0.38)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.38/docs/mapview.html),

> ### MapView
>
> **IMPORTANT:** This component is now **DEPRECATED** and will be removed in January 2017 (React Native version 0.42). This component
>   only supports iOS.
>
> Please use [`react-native-maps`](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps) by Airbnb instead of this
>   component. Our friends at Airbnb have done an amazing job building a
>   cross-platform `MapView` component that is more feature complete. It
>   is used extensively (over 9k installs / month).

Comment: Ah. OK. It doesn't say that anywhere on the page I was looking at (see my question). Probably an old version of the docs I guess.

Comment: Yeah. The documentation you are referring to is a quite old version.

Comment: It explains a lot of my frustration of the past few days. :) Just starting with React Native so I'm still trying to come to grips with it's eco-system and eccentricities.

Comment: react-native is quite fast changing so I suggest you to always follow along the same documentation version with the current version you are using.